# Redirect to another controller with a @PathVariable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

How do I redirect to another controller with a path variable in the redirect.
I tried it the following way but get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Model has no value for key 'formId'

How I implemented it:

```
Long formId = drugType.getFormId();
            view = "redirect:/pub/req/customForm/view/{formId}";
```

And received by the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST,  value = "/pub/req/customForm/view/{formId}")
String completeCustomForm(@PathVariable Long formId,
        @Valid @ModelAttribute CustomFormLayout customFormLayout,
        BindingResult errors, HttpServletRequest request, Model model,
        RedirectAttributes attr) {
```

Any ideas how I can redirect to this controller with the formId value?

Comment: do you have formId information in the controller before redirection?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try applying the parameter:

```
Long formId = drugType.getFormId();
view = "redirect:/pub/req/customForm/view/"+formId;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could either build the redirect address string:

```
return "redirect:/pub/req/customForm/view/" + drugType.getFormId();
```

Or add a model attribute named as your path variable ("`formId`") and use it in your view name (this is what the error message is telling you)

```
model.addAttribute("formId", drugType.getFormId());
return "redirect:/pub/req/customForm/view/{formId}";
```